# what is in it for him to back you

Tags: present-participles

Can one write:

> 1) What is in it for him backing you against Tom?
>
> 2) What is in it for him, backing you against Tom?
>
> 3) What is in it for his backing you against Tom?
>
> 4) What is in it for him to back you against Tom?

Are they acceptable in formal English?

How would you parse the correct ones?

Many thanks

Comment: I think you mean "backing you instead of Tom".

Comment: @user3169 - Why?  To "back X against Y" seems perfectly natural to this US English speaker.

Comment: @stangdon - That may be, but I still find all these alternatives a bit awkward. I don't know if it's the way him/you/Tom play against each other or what. I'm guessing the OP is trying to say something like, "Why would he back you against Tom?" but it's hard for me to tell for sure.

Answer (score 2):

All of your questions would be understood to mean the same, the more commonly used might be

> **What is in it for him** *(,)* **backing you against Tom?**
>   **What is in it for him to back you against Tom?**

There are essentially two statements

> **What's in it for him**

What does he get out of it?

and

> *(to)* **back***(ing)* **you against Tom**

to do this action.